# Why is $x^5 \sin x$ an odd function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Why is $x^5 \sin x$ an odd function?

Is the result just wrong? Because $f(-x)= (-x)(-x)(-x) \sin(-x) =  (-x)(-x)(-x)(-x)(-x) (-\sin x) = (-x^5)(-\sin x) = x^5 \sin x$

Comment: $x^n\sin x$ is odd if and only if $n$ is even. It is even for odd $n$.

Comment: It is an even function.

Comment: An odd function times an odd function is an _even_ function, similar to how an odd number plus an odd number is an even number.

Comment: Who told you it's an even function?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = x^5 \sin x$, then
$$f(-x) = (-x)^5 \sin (-x) = -x^5 \left( - \sin x\right) = x^5 \sin x = f(x),$$
and so $f$ is actually even.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = x^5 \sin x$.

$$f(-x) = (-x)^5 \sin(-x) =(-1)^5x^5(-\sin\ x) = x^5 \sin x = f(x) $$

It follows by definition that $f$ is even.

More generally, can you tell what happens with $f(x) = x^n \sin x$, when $n$ is even? And when $n$ is odd? Simply observe that $(-1)^n = \begin{cases} 1 &, n\ \  \text{is even}\\ -1 &, \ n\text{ is  odd} \end{cases}$.